# Cannot open multiple jquery ui dialog box in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-dialog, jsfiddle

please help with this using rails 3 and jquery-ui.
In my view i have:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contents">
    <% @questions.each do |question| %><br />
       <li>
           <button class="opendialog">Delete</button>
           <div class="info" title="Delete Request">
               Question:<b><%= question.content %></b>
           </div>
       </li>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my application.js i have:

```
$(function() {
  $('.opendialog').each(function() {  
    $.data(this, 'dialog', 
      $(this).next('.info').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true
      })
    ); 
  }).click(function() {  
      $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');
      return false;  
  });
});
```

The problem that i am having is that none of the dialogs open, when i click their respective buttons. The code works fine in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hishalv/4UJhm/), but no luck in my code.How can i solve this.In my app there are places that i open single dialog boxes and works fine, its just this code that does not want to open the dialogs when i click the respective buttons.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, i found that i was loading in my stylesheets incorrectly.
I was including the .js files like this
1). Create new project skip prototype with -J:

```
rails new -J test -d mysql
```

2). Modify the Gemfile, add JQuery:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

3). Bundle update:

```
bundle update rails
```

4). Generator the JQuery, --ui means withe JQuery UI:

```
rails generate jquery:install --ui
```

5). Modify the config/application.rb:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery jquery-ui rails application)
```

Notice how in the application.rb file I was loading application.js.

Then in my application.html.erb file i was loading in application.js like this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

However when I viewed the source of my html I noticed that the application.js was being loaded twice causing a conflict.

In application.rb I then changed the line to:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery jquery-ui rails)
```

restart server and all is good. Simple error